# How to setup network with two routers where one is VPN and second gets internet and go through first one

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn

I would like to setup network which would allow to end-user (laptop in the pic) without installing any VPN software being able to still hide under his Germany internet and location.

1. In the germany I would like to setup OpenWRT (or Asus internal software [can be any manufacture]) VPN.
2. While being in Netherlands I would like to have **Router X** configured to connect to the Germany Router using wifi/lan internet connection.

Desired output is that the laptop wherever it is (Netherlands, Belgium etc) connecting to the some internal VPN software will have fingerprint of being in Germany.

[Desired setup]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/a42J8.png

Comment: Typically, in my own use, VPN has two end points and encryption in between (VPN to Germany).  The Netherlands router is unlikely to break into it.

Comment: Good for you @John unfortunately I would like to avoid usege of any VPN from third parties(nord vpn etc). Just make VPN in my home.

Comment: Since you named your account after a (fictional) gangster I guess the question is, why do you want to do that?